# Editing component property values in the Properties tab seems to no longer work in ver 2.1.0

Tags: redhawksdr

I recently upgraded to RedHawk V2.1.0, which has fixed several of the issues I had with previous versions, but one feature that I used seems to now not work.  I have rebuilt and installed working components and waveforms.  One of the components has a unsigned short property that is configured as readwrite and has an external id in the waveform.  With v 2.0.1 I could launch and start the waveform and then view the properties in the properties tab at the bottom of the IDE window for the waveform or any component I clicked on and I could change a value in that window while the component was running or stop the component change it and restart.  With version 2.1.0 I can still override the value when launching the waveform, but after launch the properties tab at the bottom displays the original default value (not the overridden value from launch) and it is not editable when the component is started or stopped.  Was this changed intentionally or is this a bug?  It seems to be true of all properties my components have.  I have checked that these are still listed as readwrite in the prf file.

Or is there now a different way to change property values on the fly?

I should add that I am running in a domain, NOT the sandbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Action type="external" in PRF or declaring in externalproperties in SAD does NOT affect ability to edit in the Properties panel, but I found that the checkbox for "Pass on command line" DID affect this.  I am fairly certain that with v2.0.1 I was able to check pass on command line and still edit the value in the panel.  With 2.1.0 checking it makes it NOT editable but without it checked I CAN edit.  I am not sure if this change was intentional or not but at least I know how to work around it.

Comment: Do all the properties you have issues with have "Pass on command line" set?

Comment: Yes, so far that is all I have seen

Answer (score 0):

I think that I noticed this in the 2.0.5 IDE as well.  For the time being, try just removing the "external" attribute from the PRF for that property and see what you get.  I anticipate that this will be fixed in the next release of the 2.0.x and 2.1.x series.